# Write a window function Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a table:

```
+-------------------+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------+
|         session_id|  insert_dttm|           key|  value| process_name|
+-------------------+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------+
|local-1641922005078|1641922023703|test_file1.csv|Success|ProcessResult|
|local-1641922005078|1641922023704|test_file1.csv|Success|ProcessResult|
|local-1641922005078|1641922023705|test_file2.csv|Success|ProcessResult|
|local-1641922005080|1641922023706|test_file2.csv|Success|ProcessResult|
|local-1641922005080|1641922023707|test_file3.csv|Success|ProcessResult|
|local-1641922005080|1641922023708|test_file3.csv|Success|ProcessResult|
+-------------------+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------+
```

I want to get last session from this table:

```
local-1641922005080 :String
```

Can I do this using a window function?

I have solution:

```
val lastSessionId = ds.select(max(struct(col("insert_dttm"), col("session_id")))("session_id"))
                      .first.getString(0)
```

Only I also want to implement this with a window function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need here a window function since you can just sort the data in `desc` order and return the first record using `limit(1)`.

But for the sake of practice, you can use window function like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, row_number}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window


val windowSpec  = Window.orderBy(col("insert_dttm").desc)
val lastSessionId = df.withColumn("row_number", row_number.over(windowSpec)).filter("row_number=1").first.getString(0)
```

Comment: I will follow your advice.